# Can't create a view with a select with a case when clause

Tags: php, sql, oracle

If I execute the `select` part, it works and I get the information but if I try to do a view of this `select` and then call to that view it says "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist ". I have other views without the `case when` clause that works.

```
    $oracletext10="create or replace view consulta1 
     as (SELECT ArticulosCanal99.CODIGO, 
                ArticulosCanal99.UBICACION, 
                SumaArticulosenPalets.CODIGO, 
                SumaArticulosenPalets.UBICACION,
                case ArticulosCanal99.codigo when 
                    SumaArticulosenPalets.codigo then 1 end as Expr1, 
                ArticulosCanal99.UNIS_PALET_COMPLETO AS Palet_Completo 
    FROM SumaArticulosenPalets 
    RIGHT JOIN ArticulosCanal99 
       ON SumaArticulosenPalets.CODIGO = ArticulosCanal99.CODIGO)";  

    $stid10 = oci_parse($db,$oracletext10);  
    oci_execute($stid10);
```

Comment: To be able to create a view, you need direct select privileges on the underlying objects. To just issue the select part, select privileges via a role are enough.

Comment: The underlying objects are actually views that I've created and I can do a ' select' of them.

Comment: Please reread, the advice still stands. You need direct select privileges on the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on @RobvanWijk's comment:

Quoting here from the [Oracle 11.2 SQL reference's page on CREATE VIEW](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504), "The owner of the schema containing the view must have the privileges necessary to either select, insert, update, or delete rows from all the tables or views on which the view is based. **The owner must be granted these privileges directly, rather than through a role**". So your user has been granted privileges on the base tables/views of your new view through a role, and can thus execute the SELECT statement successfully. However, when you go to create a view from this SQL statement your user's role-based permissions are not sufficient: you'll need to execute the following GRANT statements to be able to create the view:

```
GRANT SELECT ON SUMAARTICULOSENPALETS TO your-user-here;
GRANT SELECT ON ARTICULOSCANAL99 TO your-user-here;
```

replacing "your-user-here" with the user name you're using.

Best of luck.